# why is node compiling greater than that way?

Tags: javascript, compilation, logic

just to test a little bit I typed in some 'greater than'.. 'or'.. ><|.. and I got the following results:

> 11<2|14 ->14
>
> 11<13|14 ->15
>
> 11<12|14 ->15
>
> 11<12|17 ->17
>
> 11<16|17 ->17
>
> 15<16|17 ->17
>
> 15<14|17 ->17

Why is the second and third block 15?

Comment: 11 is binary 1011 and 14 is binary 1110 - so if you make a logical OR then 1011 v 1110 => 1111 and that is 15 in decimal

Answer (score 3):

> 11<13|14 ->15

The `11<13|14` means: `(11 < 13 ? 1 : 0) | 14`, and `|` is a "binary or".
Therefore, what you end up doing is `1 | 14` which is `15`:

The binary representation of 14 is 8 + 4 + 2 = `1110`, and or-ing it with `1` results in `1111` which is 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15.

Comment: ..so there is just one pipe missing for less confusion.

Comment: If you expected to see `true` and `false`, then yes: all your statements would print `true` with `||` instead of `|` (because what is of the left of the `||` doesn't matter since what is at the right is not false).

Comment: No, all of the statements would *not* print `true` if `||` was used instead of `|`. The first statement would print `14`, and the last would print `17`. (The rest would be `true`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right, I was too quick ;-) `||` in JS isn't really "boolean or", but more like the trinary operator `?:`, so `11<2||14` comes down to `false?false:14`. Correct me if I'm wrong.